# Pandoc-citeproc isn't showing "p. " only the page number

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Recently I've discovered the great pandoc-citeproc filter for adding literature sources to markdown documents -- in order to convert them to PDFs with bibliographic references. However, I would prefer to avoid the substitution of "p. ".

E.g.: When citing `@einstein1934 [p. 21]` this is converted to:

- *Einstein (1934, 21)* rather then,
- *Einstein (1934, p. 21)* my preference.

The [documentation (see 24. Markdown citations)](https://pandoc.org/demos.html) seems not to specify how to escape this behaviour in the [examples](https://pandoc.org/demo/CITATIONS).

**EDIT**
This is the command I use to convert the document.

```
$ pandoc -s --bibliography sources.bib --citeproc document.md -o document.pdf
```

**/EDIT**

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is controlled by the chosen citation style. Use `--csl` with a suitable [style](https://citationstyles.org). The default, as of March 2021, is Chicago Manual of Style 17th edition. Try APA, it uses the style you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Please add the command to your answer, so that anyone can use it properly. `$ pandoc -s --bibliography sources.bib --csl apa.csl --citeproc document.md -o document.pdf`. Maybe it would also help readers to see the available styles [here. Here](https://www.zotero.org/styles?dependent=0) it is also possible to download the coresponding `CSL`-file in order to apply the required style.